Java converting range to specific integers
This is a simple Java question. I don't know what to search for in stackoverflow to get to the right question. My requirement is very simple :
Given a double value which lies between 0 and 10, convert it to an integer using the following logic.
If the double value is  >=0.0D && <0.5D output=1  
If the double value is  >=0.5D && <1.0D output=2  
If the double value is  >=1.0D && <1.5D output=3  
....................so on up till  
If the double value is  >=9.5D && <10.0D output=20

Preferred to extend the range well beyond 10.0D later on.
Don't want to keep on writing case and if else conditions.
How to achieve this efficiently ?
Not sure how I can use Math.ceil or Math.floor to achieve this.
public int convert(double d)
    {
      //logic to go here
}

Any help is appreciated. Ok to use any collections or other apis for this.
Also how to change the logic later on if the increments are not in 0.5 and want it to be variable.

Is that it?

If the double value is  >=5.0D && <1.0D output=2  did you mean `If the double value is  >=0.5D && <1.0D output=2

Multiply by 2, truncate (by casting to int) and add 1? If you want the logic to be variable, just make the "2" and "1" parts input parameters.

alternative to previous comment, and having any step (e.g. 0.5) -> divide by the step, truncate, add 1 -- obviously assuming >=5.0D && <1.0D is a typo

Decimal literals default to double sans the d suffix.

Sorry @JonSkeet  Mark Rotteveel. Yes it was a typo, changed it to 0.5 instead of 5.0. I was looking for fancy way of doing this.  Looks like the answer Jon said is the only way out. "return (int) (value * 2) + 1; "

You can do what Jon suggested and multiply the value by two and add one.
Add a range-check at the beginning:
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class RangeCheck {
    record TestCase(double input, int expected) {}

    private static final List<TestCase> testCases = List.of(
        new TestCase(Math.E, 6),
        new TestCase(Math.PI, 7),
        new TestCase(Double.MAX_VALUE, -1)
    );

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean allMatch = Stream.of(
                testCases.stream().allMatch(c -> Objects.equals(convert(c.input), c.expected)),
                testCases.stream().allMatch(c -> Objects.equals(convertEfficient(c.input), c.expected))
        ).allMatch(Boolean::booleanValue);

        // All should be true
        System.out.println(allMatch);
    }

    public static int convertEfficient(double value) {
        if (value < 0.0d || value >= 10.0d) return -1; // Return -1 for values outside the specified range
        return (int) (value * 2) + 1;
    }

    public static int convert(double value) {
        if (value >= 0.0d && value < 0.5d) return 1;
        if (value >= 0.5d && value < 1.0d) return 2;
        if (value >= 1.0d && value < 1.5d) return 3;
        if (value >= 1.5d && value < 2.0d) return 4;
        if (value >= 2.0d && value < 2.5d) return 5;
        if (value >= 2.5d && value < 3.0d) return 6;
        if (value >= 3.0d && value < 3.5d) return 7;
        if (value >= 3.5d && value < 4.0d) return 8;
        if (value >= 4.0d && value < 4.5d) return 9;
        if (value >= 4.5d && value < 5.0d) return 10;
        if (value >= 5.0d && value < 5.5d) return 11;
        if (value >= 5.5d && value < 6.0d) return 12;
        if (value >= 6.0d && value < 6.5d) return 13;
        if (value >= 6.5d && value < 7.0d) return 14;
        if (value >= 7.0d && value < 7.5d) return 15;
        if (value >= 7.5d && value < 8.0d) return 16;
        if (value >= 8.0d && value < 8.5d) return 17;
        if (value >= 8.5d && value < 9.0d) return 18;
        if (value >= 9.0d && value < 9.5d) return 19;
        if (value >= 9.5d && value < 10.0d) return 20;
        return -1; // Return -1 for values outside the specified range
    }
}


But why use 20 different if statements for this?

Mike, it's for the test-case, verifying that the convertEfficient method returns the desired values.
